# How can i call jquery using class name 

Tags: jquery

My div has no id .
can i call  a jquery function on click of that div

div identified by class used in div.

```
<div class="divclass">
```

how can i call

```
$('.divclass').click(
```

???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To assign a `click` handler, you can do this:

```
$('div.divclass').click(function() {
    alert('i was clicked');
});
```

...or this, which is the same thing:

```
$('div.divclass').bind('click', function() {
    alert('i was clicked');
});
```

**Here's an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/MAKHh/

---

**EDIT:**

As noted by *@mcgrailm*, there's another means of firing code on the click of an element called `.live()`. As well as a related one called `.delegate()`.

With `live()`, the handler will fire regardless of when the element is added to the page.

```
$('div.divclass').live('click', function() {
    alert('i was clicked');
});
```

Or with `.delegate()` you call it agains a container, and elements added to that container at any time will fire the handler.

```
$('.someContainer').delegate('div.divclass', 'click', function() {
    alert('i was clicked');
});
```

---

Or if you wanted to `.trigger()` a click event, do this:

```
$('div.divclass').click();
```

Or this:

```
$('div.divclass').trigger('click');
```

You can also call the handler without triggering the event.

```
$('div.divclass').triggerHandler('click');
```

Comment: @mcgrailm - Good point. That and `.delegate()` as well. I'll update.

Comment: Am asking a doubt or nonsense i dont know ..there are situations the div wil have 2 class.. or one class inside other consider situation <div class="divclass subclass" > . Now what i have to do?

Comment: @zod - Are you saying you only want to attach the `click` handler if *both* classes are present? If so, do `$('div.divclass.subclass').click(...`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the correct syntax:

```
$('.divclass').click(function(){
  alert('I got clicked !');
});
```

To trigger a click on the div programatically, you can do:

```
$('.divclass').click();
```

See:

- [jQuery class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)
- [click event handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/)